# Can't select individual particles in Particle Edit mode

Tags: particles

I want to delete individual particles from a particle simulation which I have baked to memory. When I enter Particle Edit mode and Point Selection mode I expect to see particle keys, yet there are none. There is nothing to select other than the entire particle system. Please see the attached blend file.

What am I doing wrong? How do I select individual keys or particles?

[image]